# Linux timeout for read() on named pipe

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

Suppose I create a named pipe on a Linux system:

```
$ mkfifo my_pipe
```

The next thing I want to do is write a little monitor program which tries to `read()` from `my_pipe`, but times out after a while. In the following pseudo-code, I have used a fictional function `wait_for_avail(fd, timeout_ms)`:

```
int fd = open("my_pipe", O_RDONLY);
while (1) {
    //Fictional wait_for_avail(fd, timeout_ms). Is there a real function
    //that has this behaviour?
    int rc = wait_for_avail(fd, 500);
    if (rc == 1) {
        char buf[64];
        read(fd, buf, 64);
        //do something with buf
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Timed out while reading from my_pipe\n");
        //do something else in the program
    }
}
```

I thought `poll` with the `POLLIN` flag might work, but it does not. From my simple trials, I have found that it simply waits until another process has *opened* the named pipe for writing (but not for data to be available, i.e. `read()` would not block). By the way, for some reason, `poll` ignores your timeout and just seems to block forever until another process opens the pipe.

The only other solution I can think of is to `open()` the file with `O_NONBLOCK`, and sort of manually watch the time going by as I constantly try `read()`ing with a count of 0 bytes.

Is there a better solution out there?

EDIT: The process I have here blocks on opening the named pipe. However, if you use the `O_NONBLOCK` flag, the file opens right away. At that point, `poll()` can be used to wait (with an optional timeout) for the other end of the pipe to be opened for writing.

However, this still does have the behaviour of implementing a timeout for the `read()` function. It still appears to block as soon as you call `read()` (even if the pipe was opened with `O_NONBLOCK`)

Comment: It's not `read` that is blocking but `open`.

Comment: Open in non-blocking mode, then poll waiting for a timeout or something to open the other end of the fifo.

Comment: It seems that `poll` does not wait for bytes to be available. When used with a pipe, `poll` with `POLLIN` waits for the "other end" of the pipe to be opened. With regular files, `POLLIN` always returns right away

Comment: @Mahkoe, you are not reading my first comment.  Your process is never even getting past `open`.  `open` will not return until someone opens the other end of the pipe, and there's no point in calling `read` until `open` succeeds.

Comment: Regular files will never block; a read will always succeed or fail right away. Thus it's always in a `POLLIN` state when queried.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about opening the fifo in non-blocking mode is correct. If you do that, `poll()`/`select()`/etc. can be used to wait for the other end to be opened, or timeout first.

The following example program just runs in an infinite loop waiting for other programs to write to `my_pipe` and echos the written text, with the occasional status update when there's no data or writer:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  while (1) {
    int fd = open("my_pipe", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0) {
      perror("open");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct pollfd waiter = {.fd = fd, .events = POLLIN};

    while (1) {
      // 10 second timeout
      switch (poll(&waiter, 1, 10 * 1000)) {
      case 0:
        puts("The fifo timed out.");
        break;
      case 1:
        if (waiter.revents & POLLIN) {
          char buffer[BUFSIZ];
          ssize_t len = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
          if (len < 0) {
            perror("read");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
          }
          buffer[len] = '\0';
          printf("Read: %s\n", buffer);
        } else if (waiter.revents & POLLERR) {
          puts("Got a POLLERR");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else if (waiter.revents & POLLHUP) {
          // Writer closed its end
          goto closed;
        }
        break;
      default:
        perror("poll");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }
  closed:
    if (close(fd) < 0) {
      perror("close");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this code, the poll returns as soon as the pipe is opened at the other end. From that point forward, `poll()` never waits. What ends up happening is that the `read()` function gets called in a loop. Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: And by the way, it appears `O_NONBLOCK` doesn't do anything for `read()`ing names pipes. See https://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo

Comment: @Mahkoe ? If you open a connection to the write end and don't send any data (Like with `cat > my_pipe`, you'll see timeout messages every 10 seconds.

Comment: I must have made a mistake. Let me look at my code more carefully and try again

Comment: @Shawn: `SIGPIPE` is raised when you attempt to **write** to a closed pipe.  It's never raised by reading, AFAIK.

Comment: @Shawn how do you know if there is data available in the pipe? Sounds like it's exactly what I need

Comment: @NateEldredge Doh, yeah. `read()` returns 0 instead after the last writer closes. My bad.

Comment: @Mahkoe That's what `poll()` and friends do.

Comment: @Shawn I'm really stumped here. I put my code at this location: https://pastebin.com/ppQEnnku
As soon as someone opens the pipe (and even if they close it) poll always returns immediately

Comment: @Mahkoe With that, if the pipe is closed, `poll()` will return right away with `POLLHUP` in the `revents`. And then `read()` returns 0, and the loop repeats... run your program under `strace` to see (It'll be spammy).

Comment: Okay, I think I finally understand what's going on. This technique in your answer is to wait with a timeout until someone opens the pipe for writing, presumably with the intention to write something right away (instead of two processes connected by a pipe where the reader is constantly checking for messages from the writer).
I think that this technique, combined with setting a SIGALRM timer before calling `read()` should work for what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of help and patience from @Shawn, I managed to come up with an answer I found satisfying. Here are the contents of a file called `pipe_watcher.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //printf etc.
#include <errno.h>  //errno
#include <string.h> //perror
#include <signal.h> //SIGALRM, sigaction, sigset
#include <time.h>   //timer_create, timer_settime
#include <fcntl.h>  //open, O_RDONLY
#include <unistd.h> //close

/* This code demonstrates how you can monitor a named pipe with timeouts on the
 * read() system call.
 * 
 * Compile with:
 * 
 *  gcc -o pipe_watcher pipe_watcher.c -lrt
 * 
 * And run with:
 * 
 *  ./pipe_watcher PIPE_FILENAME
*/

//Just needed a dummy handler
void sigalrm_handler(int s) {
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Check input argument count
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("Usage:\n");
        puts("\t./pipe_watcher PIPE_FILENAME");
        return -1;
    }

    //Create a timer object
    timer_t clk;
    int rc = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &clk);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("Could not create CLOCK_REALTIME timer");
        return -1;
    }

    //Create some time values for use with timer_settime
    struct itimerspec half_second = {
        .it_interval = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0},
        .it_value = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 500000000}
    };

    struct itimerspec stop_timer = {
        .it_interval = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0},
        .it_value = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0}
    };

    //Set up SIGALRM handler
    struct sigaction sigalrm_act = {
        .sa_handler = sigalrm_handler,
        .sa_flags = 0
    };
    sigemptyset(&sigalrm_act.sa_mask);
    rc = sigaction(SIGALRM, &sigalrm_act, NULL);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("Could not register signal handler");
        timer_delete(clk);
        return -1;
    }

    //We deliberately omit O_NONBLOCK, since we want blocking behaviour on
    //read(), and we're willing to tolerate dealing with the blocking open()
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        char msg[80];
        sprintf(msg, "Could not open [%s]", argv[1]);
        perror(msg);
        timer_delete(clk);
        return -1;
    }

    puts("File opened");

    while (1) {
        //Buffer to read() into
        char buf[80];
        int len;

        //Set up a timer to interrupt the read() call after 0.5 seconds
        timer_settime(clk, 0, &half_second, NULL);

        //Issue read() system call
        len = read(fd, buf, 80);

        //Check for errors. The else-if checks for EOF
        if (len < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                //This means we got interrupted by the timer; we can keep going
                fprintf(stderr, "Timeout, trying again\n");
                continue;
            } else {     
                //Something really bad happened. Time to quit.       
                perror("read() failed");
                //No point waiting for the timer anymore
                timer_settime(clk, 0, &stop_timer, NULL);
                break;
            }
        } else if (len == 0) {
            puts("Reached end of file");
            break;
        }

        //No error or EOF; stop the timer and print the results
        timer_settime(clk, 0, &stop_timer, NULL);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, len);
    }

    //Cleanup after ourselves
    timer_delete(clk);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The technique is to set up a timer before a (blocking) `read()` call. Then, we can simply check the return value of `read()` to see if it was interrupted due to a timeout, if a general error occurred, if EOF was reached, or if it successfully read data.

There's only one snag: you can't open the file in non-blocking mode; this causes `open()` to block until another process opens the pipe for writing. However, in my application this is actually a desirable feature. You could also set up SIGALRM to enforce a timeout on the `open()`, or maybe do it in another thread.

In fact, this technique should work with any other system call, so I might put together a little helper library to make this pattern easier to use.

**EDIT**

One more thing: it is very important to not use the `SA_RESTART` flag when registering the signal handler. Otherwise, even if a system call is interrupted by a signal, Linux will try it again after the signal is handled.